# How does one remove foreign-keys if the table they're on doesn't exist?

Tags: postgresql, corruption, postgresql-8.4

Scenario:

```
DELETE FROM table_x WHERE id not in (1,2,3,4)
```

Response:

> update or delete on table "table_x" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk1" on table "table_y" DETAIL:  Key (table_x_id)=(7) is still
>   referenced from table "table_y".

- emptied 'table_y' of all records
- FK didn't show in the FK list for 'table_y'
- deleted the table 'table_y' completely

We still get this message, so the assumption is that there is a rouge record somewhere in the `pg_constraints` table. Looking for the constraint 'fk1' we find two records and remove them.

Query:

```
delete from pg_constraint where conname = 'fk1'
```

Now we get THIS error:

> [Err] ERROR:  cache lookup failed for constraint 868152

At this point I'm fairly certain that we need to clean up some records, but not sure how - anybody have experience in this that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: [`VACUUM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-vacuum.html) lately?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad index.  Note that the solutions here are partial.  You need to find out what is the root cause.  Causes I have seen in the past include failing hard drives and RAM, and overheating or failing CPU's.

Foreign key constraints hit unique indexes.    If you are seeing weird behavior here the issue may be a bad index.  Try reindexing the tables or even whole databases involved to get rid of the problem.

I don't think this is caused by failing to vacuum.  xid wraparound is nasty when it happens but recent versions go to great lengths to keep that from happening.  Chances are this is index corruption at best.  If not that, it is data corruption (note that index corruption occurs IME far more frequently, but data corruption occurs from all the same causes, so find the root of the problem stat).